# UK Visa: Do they need/require third country visa at time of application?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas

This question is an extension of: [Schengen Visa Rejected/Refunded (?)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181443/schengen-visa-rejected-refunded)

As it concerns a different governing body, I have created a new question. To summarize, EU is not issuing me a visa since I am flying in from London to EU/Estonia (citizen of India/living in Singapore) . They are asking me to get the UK visa first. My questions about the UK visa are:

1. Does the UK visa application require me to furnish my outbound plans at the time of application? For example: mentioning how I will be exiting UK/with proof of return tix to Singapore/India or if I am going to a third country, a visa of that country
2. If the answer to 1) is yes, can I be flexible with my plans? for eg: mention that I am flying back to Singapore at time of application with proof and then later travel to EU with a valid Schengen visa (in case I am issued that eventually which should mostly be the case)

In both cases, at the time of boarding, I'll make sure I have the relevant flight tickets booked. **Ideally**, I would want to travel from London to EU but I am worried if I mention this in my application, they will ask me to furnish the Schengen visa (which I can't get because EU wants me to get the UK first). Not trying to take advantage of the visa process but seems like I have found myself stuck in the circular loop of getting the UK + Schengen visa

Comment: Showing booked tickets when applying for a UK visitor visa is not required unless you are transiting (less than 48 hours); in fact, UKVI specifically advises applicants *not to book* before getting the decision https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: I suppose you are travelling via the UK on your way out as well? It is a lot more likely that they ask for a visa for your outbound travel rather than for the inbound travel. They shouldn’t care if you can get to Schengen, what they really care about is that you can get out! So you should normally apply for visas in reverse order: I suppose you have a residence permit for SG, so visa for the UK (on your way back), visa for Schengen, visa for the UK (on your way in). But how long are you staying in the UK each way and will you have a single ticket? That may change the type of visa for the UK.

Comment: I am flying out from Paris to SG (where I do have a valid visa). I was applying for the visas in reverse order (you may see the linked question for more details) but the Estonian embassy basically said that I need the UK visa first if I am flying in from London to Tallinn (in Estonia). It's a weird one for sure. Staying in UK for 16 days or so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the UK visa application require me to furnish my outbound plans at the time of application?

Yes, however for a Standard Visitor visa you are **not** required to show travel bookings.

- You’ll need to provide the following information in your online application:
- the dates you’re planning to travel to the UK
- where you’ll be staying during your visit
- how much you think your trip will cost

Source: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/apply-standard-visitor-visa

The guidance on documents you should not use as evidence includes:

- hotel bookings
- flight bookings (unless transiting)

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

In your other question you mention in a comment that you plan to stay two weeks in the UK.  If a round trip from your country of residence to the UK is credible, you can show you have the means to pay for it, and a compelling reason to leave at the end of the visit (job, family ties etc) I don’t see any reason why you cannot present that plan to the UK. They don’t care where you leave **to**, only that you **will** leave.

> If I am going to a third country from the UK, do I need a visa of that country?

**Yes** if if you’ll be going through UK border control but leaving the UK within 48 hours.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does that mean I can (most probably) get by with getting the UK visa w/o mentioning Schengen anywhere as long as I have enough funds + NOC/employment letter/visa showing my connection to Singapore?

Maybe, as an extra precaution, I can book flight back to SG anyway from London and cancel it later in case Schengen plan materializes. Ready to bear the cancellation charges I guess.

Comment: @IamJojo45 Yes, IMHO there is nothing to stop you treating your UK visit as a separate itinerary.  You  can provide suitable evidence of ties to SG to support your intention to leave the UK. However, since providing flight bookings with an application is explicitly **not** required,  you should not expect doing so to necessarily add much weight to the application.